# ghc.exe could not execute ld.exe while installing zlib

Tags: haskell, installation, zlib, cabal

Im using

- Windows 10
- cabal-install version 3.2.0.0
- GHC version 8.10.2

While trying to install zlib via

`cabal install zlib`

I get:

```
Building library for zlib-0.6.2.2..
[1 of 5] Compiling Codec.Compression.Zlib.Stream ( dist\build\Codec\Compression\Zlib\Stream.hs, dist\build\Codec\Compression\Zlib\Stream.o )
ghc.exe: could not execute: C:/GitLabRunner/builds/2WeHDSFP/0/ghc/ghc/inplace/mingw/bin/ld.exe
```

Comment: IIRC, `8.10.2` has problems on Windows.

Comment: There is a supposed workaround here: https://www.stackage.org/blog/2020/08/ghc-8-10-2-windows-workaround

Answer (score 1):

As the comments discuss, that version of ghc is known broken on windows. (cf https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/issues/18550). I suggest upgrading to ghc 8.10.5